# Keypress function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, keypress

I am trying to and have to `keypress` the letter 'A' with JavaScript.
In the code below, there is an `alert('hello')` box that indicates that the code is executing.

But this code doesn't set any values to the "login-email" input (which is a textbox).

What can be wrong with the code?

```js
          function presskey()
          { 
              var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
              if (e.initKeyboardEvent)
              {
                  alert('hello'); e.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, document.defaultView, 'A', 0, '', false, '');
              }
              document.getElementById('login-email').dispatchEvent(e);
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to note that [`.initKeyboardEvent()` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent). What you likely want is the event constructor (Ex. for an 'input' event, `new InputEvent()`, as seen in the code below)

That said, the rest of my answer assumes the question should actually be "How do I manually trigger input events on a textbox?". Please let me know if this isn't actually what you want, but the same concepts should apply to other types of events.

...if this is your actual question, I can show you how I would start solving this problem:

```js
const typeInto = (el, data) => {
  // Note the use of the InputEvent constructor
  const e = new InputEvent('input', {
    inputType: 'insertText',
    data,
  })
  
  // Manually add the text to element.value
  el.value += data
  
  // Fire the event like you were doing
  el.dispatchEvent(e)
}

// Get element
const el = document.querySelector('.js-login-email')

// Add an event listener for the 'input' event, to prove it's working
el.addEventListener('input', e => {
  console.log(`${e.inputType}: ${e.data}`)
})

// Example "typeInto" usage: call for each letter in the string below
'example@example.com'.split('').forEach(letter => {
  typeInto(el, letter)
})
```

```html
<input type="email" class="js-login-email"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was after! I was also a little confused about the .initKeyboardEvent() as it was different for chrome and firefox and now when it was deprecated also that made sense :) I can't thank you enough!!! Thank you!

Comment: So glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Mb you try addEventListener?

```
elem.AddEventListener("keypress", (e) => {

    var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');

    if(e.keyCode === 65) {
        //...
    }

    document.getElementById('login-email').dispatchEvent(e);

});
```

Comment: I dont know how that works. I dont know if I need to combine my code with your code. I am little lost when it comes to the logic here? The above code "listens" for a keypress, but the keypress doesn't work in my first post?

Comment: @Andreas This code listen your keypress , and if code of this keypress is 65("A"), running your function .
Sorry , my english so low

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I posted an answer where I try to combine my code with yours but I cant understand how to do it?

Comment: It should be elem.addEventListener, instead of elem.AddEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it by makeing `keydown` event then you can get your **button** keycode

like this

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  console.log(event.keyCode)
});
```

so in your code it will be like this

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {

  if(event.keyCode === 65){
     console.log('hello, world');
  }
}, true);
```

if you don't know which keycode you need to check this [website](https://keycode.info/) will give you the code for each key

or if you want do it from your key name you can make it like this

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {

  console.log(event.key)
});
```

> **NOTE**: the key code for each button is come from assci code
> if you don't know what is it you can check this [link](https://www.ascii-code.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't an eventlistener just "listens" for a keydown? or do I not understand. Shouldn't I keypress something in the first place like in my first post?

Comment: you should add `eventlistener` to check every time this event fires

Comment: I am not sure that I need the evenlistener? The problem is to programatically put the letter "A" into the 'login-email' input box. I will not type anything on the keyboard.

Comment: do you want only add `A` letter in your input value after your page loads ?

Comment: I will later put an email letter by letter like: email@hotmail.com on page load(So i will then put the letters with a loop). But the important thing is to simulate keypress and not just put it as a .value since the input box requires to actually type it down.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to combine the code now but are not sure if I do this right.

Please notice that I want to programatically press the letter "A" into the 'login-email' box by running the presskey() function. I tried to run the below code but only the alert box is shown?

```js
              function presskey()
              { 
                  var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
                  if (e.initKeyboardEvent)
                  {
                      alert('hello'); e.initKeyboardEvent('keypress', true, true, document.defaultView, 'A', 0, '', false, '');
                  }
                  document.getElementById('login-email').dispatchEvent(e);
              }


var elem = document.getElementById('login-email');
elem.AddEventListener("keypress", (e) => {

    var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
    if(e.keyCode === 65) {
        //...
    }
    document.getElementById('login-email').dispatchEvent(e);
});
```